# Custom attributes hint don't popup in Android Studio IntelliJ

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been struggling with this problem for one entire day. I'm looking for someone that helps me, or for someone that can test it on his Android Studio installation.

I published a widget on github: [Rotating knob selector](https://github.com/BeppiMenozzi/Knob), but since I started developping it I had to struggle with Android Studio that wouldn't show me the custom attributes defined as styleable, as you can see from this capture:
[image: All custom attributes are missing!]

The problem stands only in the popup suggestions by Android Studio, because on the other hand, any custom attribute is correctly checked and no "No resource identifier found" error is thrown. Everything works fine.

As an extract of the code, that you can browse entirely on github:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="KnobSelector">
    <attr name="kNumberOfStates" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="kDefaultState" format="integer"/>
```

I've been looking everywhere and I think that this is a bug, but I tried a lot of things:

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Remove all .iml files and .idea directories
- Copy only relevant java and xml text file and recreating the whole project
- Browsing in setups and configs everywhere

Now it looks that also the exported library on github soffers of the same **really annoying** problem.
Is there anyone that knows a solution?
I'd also appreciate a test by a user with a clean Android Studio installation with that library, to understand at least if it's a Android Studio problem, or a project problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.beppi.knoblibrary"` to layout using your widget?

Comment: Android Studio doesn't allow me to do that, stating that with Gradle I always have to put xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of head-banging I found the solution. I hope that this will help people like me banging their heads a little less.

My problem was that **the view name**

> it.beppi.knoblibrary.Knob

**didn't match exactly the attributes name**

> declare-styleable name="KnobSelector"

although everything worked, because inside the code I was referring to KnobSelector, **IntelliJ Android Studio didn't actually know it and didn't popup with the available custom attributes as wanted.**

Note that there were **absolutely no compile nor runtime errors**, only the hints with the possible custom attributes didn't popup. This suggests me that probably at runtime the custom attributes are all put in a same big pack, based on the *app:* declaration, while during the editing an additional filter hides the uncorrect attributes, basing on declaration *and* view/attributes name.

The solution was simple. Refactored (shift-F6) this way

> declare-styleable name="Knob"

and recompiled (ctrl-F9). This fixed it, after days.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the attributes. The popup won't load custom attributes but you can still add them manually and project will compile correctly. Definitely is a Studio issue.

Tested on Android Studio 2.3 Canary 2.

Comment: Did you test it? Does it give the same problems on your AS too?

Comment: Yes, tested on https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar library. I tried with app: and android: and no luck. This is a long time known issue.